# histogram data from qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using qplot function to generate a histogram. It generates nice plots and i am very happy with the graphics. I also want to print the histogram data, is there any way to retrieve that from `qplot()` return object? I was using `hist()` function, which gives the data if we add the option `plot = FALSE`, same is not working with `qplot()`.

Comment: I believe this will be possible with ggplot2 version 0.3 that is scheduled to be released to CRAN on March 1st.

Comment: In the meantime, it's best to explictly specify the breaks (and when you do that, you obviously know where they are).

Comment: @Andrie 0.9, not 0.3 ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `ggplot_build()` to get actual data used to make `ggplot()` histogram. They are stored in list element `data` - midpoints for bars are in column `x` and counts are in column `count`.

```
 p<-ggplot_build(ggplot(movies,aes(x=rating))+geom_histogram())

 head(p$data[[1]])
    y count    x   ndensity     ncount     density PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax
1   0     0 0.75 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000000000     1     1    0    0  0.6  0.9
2 150   150 1.05 0.02967946 0.02967946 0.008505137     1     1    0  150  0.9  1.2
3 122   122 1.35 0.02413930 0.02413930 0.006917512     1     1    0  122  1.2  1.5
4 199   199 1.65 0.03937475 0.03937475 0.011283482     1     1    0  199  1.5  1.8
5 366   366 1.95 0.07241789 0.07241789 0.020752535     1     1    0  366  1.8  2.1
6 409   409 2.25 0.08092600 0.08092600 0.023190674     1     1    0  409  2.1  2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)

fakeDF <- data.frame(group = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 50, replace = T),
                 rand = sample(50:100, 50))

plot <- ggplot(fakeDF, aes(x = group, y = rand, group = group, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

table <- tableGrob(head(fakeDF))

grid.arrange(plot,
           table,
           ncol = 2)
```

[image]